# How to vectorize an iterative operation on a 2D and 1D NumPy array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to speed up my code to take full advantage of NumPy's vectorization.  I've been able to vectorize all of the computations in the majority of my code (`clr/vlr` functions) which I believe is the optimum for NumPy.  I don't believe these can be sped up anymore as `np.einsum` doesn't really apply.  I can't figure out how to vectorize the `rho` function. In particular, it's this nested for-loop that is giving me trouble: `1 - (ratios[i,j]/ (variances[i] + variances[j]))`.  I've tried using `np.meshgrid` to try and expand the variances but this didn't work.  I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) on `np.einsum` but, still, it's a bit confusing and I'm still not sure if it applies to this situation as it involves more operations than dot products and matrix multiplication.

**Does anyone know how to vectorize this function?**

Extra, are there any suggestions to speed up my code for the previous 2 function?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def clr(X):
    index = None
    labels = None
    if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
        index = X.index
        labels = X.columns
        X = X.values
    X_log = np.log(X)
    geometric_mean = X_log.mean(axis=1)
    X_clr = X_log - geometric_mean[:,np.newaxis]
    if labels is not None:
        X_clr = pd.DataFrame(X_clr, index=index, columns=labels)
    return X_clr

def vlr(X):
    labels = None
    if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
        labels = X.columns
        X = X.values
    n,m = X.shape
    X_log = np.log(X)
    covariance = np.cov(X_log.T)
    diagonal = np.diagonal(covariance)
    output = -2*covariance + diagonal[:,np.newaxis] + diagonal
    if labels is not None:
        output = pd.DataFrame(output, index=labels, columns=labels)
    return output

def rho(X):
    n, m = X.shape
    labels = None
    if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
        labels = X.columns
        X = X.values

    ratios = vlr(X)
    X_clr = clr(X)
    variances = np.var(X_clr, axis=0)

    # How to vectorize?
    rhos = np.ones_like(ratios)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,m):
            coef = 1 - (ratios[i,j]/ (variances[i] + variances[j]))
            rhos[i,j] = rhos[j,i] = coef

    if labels is not None:
        rhos = pd.DataFrame(rhos, index=labels, columns=labels)
    return rhos

# Load data
X_iris = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/dR59vTD4", sep="\t", index_col=0)
# Calculation
print(rho(X_iris))
#               sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
# sepal_length      1.000000     0.855012     -0.796224    -0.796770
# sepal_width       0.855012     1.000000     -0.670387    -0.964775
# petal_length     -0.796224    -0.670387      1.000000     0.493560
# petal_width      -0.796770    -0.964775      0.493560     1.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the loops:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,m):
        coef = 1 - (ratios[i,j]/ (variances[i] + variances[j]))
        rhos[i,j] = rhos[j,i] = coef
```

with:

```
rhos = 1 - ratios / np.add.outer(variances, variances)
```

`np.add.outer(variances, variances)` takes the outer sum of `variances`. For example:

```
np.add.outer(range(3), range(3))
>>> array([[0, 1, 2],
           [1, 2, 3],
           [2, 3, 4]])
```

Given the shape of your arrays and the loop math we can  do `ratios / variances[i] + variances[j]` all at once using the code above.

And just to confirm:

```
# original loop
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,m):
        coef = 1 - (ratios[i,j]/ (variances[i] + variances[j]))
        rhos[i,j] = rhos[j,i] = coef

# array math replacement
rhos2 = 1-ratios / np.add.outer(variances, variances)
np.allclose(rhos, rhos2)
>>> True
```